# How to run Spring Samples?

Tags: spring

I check out mvc-ajax project into eclipse from this svn address
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples
and run it on server,but got the following error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:/home/tom/source/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/mvc-ajax/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:181)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:182)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:383)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:446)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix this issue by remove jsp-api.jar.
Not sure this is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse: Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Server Runtime.
Then choose your server.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [c.tld](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/taglibs/standard/trunk/impl/src/main/resources/META-INF/tlds/c.tld) taglib. Make sure you deploy it.

Comment: do you mean jstl-1.2.jar? I can find it in the right folder,and I can find the c.tld file in the jar package.

Comment: I set it in /etc/enviroment

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin"
CLASSPATH=.:/usr/lib/jvm/java/jdk1.6.0_21/lib
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java/jdk1.6.0_21

Comment: looks good, I would then remove all TLD path info from web.xml and let tomcat auto-discover the TLDs

Comment: There is no tld declare in web.xml. 
:(

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce this problem so this is a shot in the dark, but I often find I can fix unexpected deployment issues by cleaning my tomcat instance in Eclipse.  Right click tomcat in your Servers view, and select Clean...

Comment: Could you explain how do you run this demo?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to the problem you were facing, while trying to solve mine.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051865/problem-running-spring-3-mvc-basic-sample) post proposes to comment the following dependences (due to problems with eclipse):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Kind Regards,
Despot

Answer (score 0):

Even I too was facing the same problem while deploying into tomcat 6 server. I solved it by copying the jstl-1.2.jar into tomcat lib folder and solved.